# Change primary key to a nullable column without losing data

Tags: sql-server-2005, primary-key

I have a table in which i have some data.

I have a primary key on a column, but I want to change it to another column which I rencently added.
I added the column as nullable, I updated it to be able to make it NOT NULL.

I used

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable MODIFY Termdefid INT NOT NULL
```

but I receive the error

> Incorrect syntax near 'MODIFY'.

After that I want to do this (after I drop the current PK, of course) :

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_MyTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [TermdefID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

I am not able to make my new column `NOT NULL`. This is my problem. How can I do this?

I use SQL Server 2005, maybe this is my problem!

Comment: Replace `MODIFY` with `ALTER COLUMN`

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server, the primary key column(s) **cannot be nullable**

Also: your `ALTER TABLE` command is invalid for SQL Server - it should be:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable 
ALTER COLUMN Termdefid INT NOT NULL
```

But again: if that column is part of your primary key, **it cannot be nullable**.

See the relevant [MSDN documentation on Primary Key Constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191236%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

> *A table can have only one PRIMARY KEY constraint, and **a column that participates in the PRIMARY KEY constraint cannot accept null values**. Because PRIMARY KEY constraints guarantee unique data, they are frequently defined on an identity column.*

Comment: Thank You, marc_s! It worked, i didn't know i had to put ALTER instead of modify. I know my PK should not accept null, this is why I want to set it to NOT NULL. You cannot put a primary key to a nullable column anyway, you will receive an error. Thank you for the answer, it worked :)